# VS Code Omnisharp Intellisense stopped working

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I was working with VS Code and everything was fine, now out of nowhere there is a problem with the intellisense caused by Omnisharp in my opinion. I'm with Macbook Air M1 (2020) with Ventura 13.0.1, also I'm with the latest .Net SDK 6.0.402. The intellisense is not working at all, I reinstalled the C# extension from Microsoft, but it didn't fix the problem. What can cause this issue ?!

Thanks in advance to all of you!!

> Starting OmniSharp server at 11/15/2022, 1:12:50 AM
> Target: /Users/kalinstoev/Dev/Reactivities/API
>
> OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.402 .
> Path: /Users/kalinstoev/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2-darwin-arm64/.omnisharp/1.39.2-net6.0/OmniSharp.dll
> PID: 952
>
> [STDERR] Unhandled exception.  [ERROR] A .NET 6 SDK for arm64 was not
> found. Please install the latest arm64 SDK from
> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0. [ERROR] Error:
> OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the
> 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay
> (one minute).

**UPDATE 15.11.22**

After Reinstalling VS Code for Mac and manually deleted the Omnisharp folders from inside the .vscode folder, there is no change. Also downgrading the version of the C# Extension to 1.25.1 didn't change anything... This is the new error when I add the new SDK..

> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
> file or assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.403/dotnet.dll'.
> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> ```
> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> ```
>
> '/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.403/dotnet.dll'. An attempt was
> made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> ```
> File name: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.403/dotnet.dll'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on the same hardware. I fell back to the 1.24.1 version [edit: of the C# extension]. Nothing above that one would work for me.

Comment: I just got my M1 restored and I think there is something messed up with the registry or with the dotnet.dll or with the path or I don't know. This was the only solution that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix to the problem. I restore my whole Macbook, because of the M1 Arm64 settings, and also the dotnet-uinstall-tool dosen't worked at all, so I just came with this solution. After the restore, I installed only .Net 6.0.403 and 7.0.0 SDKs and now everything is working fine with both VS Code and VS 22. Omnisharp also worked fine as it should be. In my opinion, something with the .Net SDKs and Runtimes path went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the C# extension to version 1.25.1

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_install-previous-versions

Comment: I tried and again the Omnishap server is not responding, the SDK is installed, but again I'm having this error in the Output Console.

Answer (score 0):

(On Windows)
I had the same error message, but it was complaining to this folder (ending with `ia32` - I should have the x64-version):

```
$HOME/.vscode/extension/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.4-win32-ia32
```

This folder will be kept even when uninstalling the extension.

I solved my issue by:

- uninstalling the vscode extension (`C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by Omnisharp)`),
- manually deleting the folder in my `$HOME/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.4-win32-ia32`
- reinstall the extension

After reinstalling the extension, I see that the new folder is correct architecture:

```
ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.4-win32-x64
```